# How to retain the previous marked option in a php quiz

Tags: php

I am making a PHP project which is supposed to conduct quizzes . For every "next" I am retrieving a question from database and when ever I I use my "previous" button functionality I losses the option which I had marked (I am using radio buttons for marking the correct option) and also for every prev and next button I am retrieving data from database i.e. I don't have all the questions with me before starting the quiz , I am accessing database for every next and prev functionality.
Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Use sessions or cookies. And before you get someone to give you the solution, try researching those topics a little.

Comment: How are your radio buttons added to the page? All you'd have to do is give the selected one a `checked` property - assuming you've stored the selected property somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider stocking the answers in $_SESSION variables so that they will be available at all time

Comment: How to use session variable to keep track of radio buttons values.It will be helpful if some example code or reference will be given

Comment: Check idipous answer. And add some extra verification for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of each quiz step you should have `session_start();` and then when you submit your form/quiz step to progress to a new page you should do something like:

```
$_SESSION['step1']['nameOfRadioFormElemnt'] = $_POST['nameOfRadioFormElemnt'];
```

Then whenever you want to get the posted value back you just access `$_SESSION['step1']'nameOfRadioFormElemnt']`

Hope this helps. For more info just check `http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php`